# linux shared library linking error

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, ld, openframeworks

When Building an openframeworks application, I had the following linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /[...]/openframeworks/addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib/linux64/libopencv_core.a(persistence.o): undefined reference to symbol 'gzclose'

/usr/bin/ld: note: 'gzclose' is defined in DSO /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
```

So I added z to the cmake file and got a new error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /[...]/openframeworks/addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib/linux64/libopencv_core.a(persistence.o): undefined reference to symbol 'gzclose'

/usr/bin/ld: note: 'gzclose' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so so try adding it to the linker command line

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
```

It's like the linker is looking for a different place to NOT find gzclose....  Could someone perhaps explain what is happening, why, and how to fix it?

when I run  `$ ldconfig -v | grep libz`  
I get

```
 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.3.4
```

and there is a libz.so.1.2.3.4 in two places:

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4 
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
```

My `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is:

```
:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I'm running 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 3.2.0-58-generic, gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04)

Thanks!
B

Comment: Looks like a 32-bit/64-bit problem.  Are you are compiling your code as 32-bit and trying to link it to a 64 bit library.

Comment: No, i'm compiling the code as 64 bit....

Comment: Did you add `z` *after* `opencv_core` (so it appears after `opencv_core` in the linker command line)?  If so, it might help to see your full link command - just run `make VERBOSE=1`

Comment: which OF version are your working with and where did you get it from? did you run the `install_dependencies.sh` script?

Comment: I've got the very same problem with `libopencv_core.a (persistence.o)`. Damn OpenCV!